# Xamarin debugging issues

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I can't debug a xamarin app with my phone. Below are the errors I get whenever i tried debugging with android phone. 
Assistance please!

Deployment failed because of an internal error: Unexpected install output: pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_15.apk
Failure [ Have not classes.dex in package ! ]

Deployment failed

[image]

Comment: I have edited it Pang

Answer (score 0):

(can't comment so adding this here instead)
I'd start by changing the target framework as per the output you've posted, so they match, i.e. are both Android 6.0